# I would like to animate through an NSArray of strings

Tags: ios, animation, nsarray

I have an NSArray of strings that I would like to animate with a simple fade in/out animation.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     fade in
|     String 1 ---> displayed in UILabel
|     fade out
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

followed by

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     fade in
|     String 2
|     fade out
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

etc...

Each one holding it's position for about 5 seconds before it continues to the next item in the array. I'm not sure where to start... I know how to perform animations but I'm not quite sure how to animate through an array of strings with a 5 second (non-thread-blocking) pause on each iteration. Any ideas?

**UPDATE MY SOLUTION BASED ON ACCEPTED ANSWER**

```
- (void)startTimer {
    arrayIndex = 0;

    NSArray *myarray = [alerts_dict allValues]; 
    breakingLabel.text = [myarray objectAtIndex:frameCount];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    breakingLabel.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    arrayIndex++;
    pauseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(myFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)myFunction {    

   [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^() {
       breakingLabel.alpha = 0;
   }
   completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       NSArray *myarray = [alerts_dict allValues]; 

       if (arrayIndex == [myarray count])
           arrayIndex = 0;

       breakingLabel.text = [myarray objectAtIndex:arrayIndex];

       arrayIndex++;

       [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^() {
           breakingLabel.alpha = 1;
       } completion:nil];
   }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily using block animations:

1. Animate label's `alpha` down to 0.0
2. On completion: set its `text` to the new string and animate it's `alpha` back to 1.0 (or original value, whatever it was)

This routine can be invoked repeatedly by an `NSTimer` timeout callback. Just instantiate a timer with interval 5.0, specify the callback and schedule it to run in the run loop like this:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self
                  selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

(...)

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    // call the method to update the label with the next string in the array
    // or invalidate the timer if you've reached the end of array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

Set the string's alpha to 0 in viewDidLoad: using this piece of code

```
for (UILabel *label in labelArray) {
     label.alpha = 0;
}
```

Then in viewWillAppear: or viewDidAppear: put this code (depends on what you want, want it to start just after the view appeared or not)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     [self animateView:[labelArray objectAtIndex:i] withDelay:i * 5];
}
```

And then the implementation of that method will be something like:

```
- (void)animateView:(UIView *)view withDelay:(float)delay {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
          view.alpha = 1.0;
     } completion:^(BOOL completed) {
          [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
               view.alpha = 0.0];
          }];
     }];
}
```

Of course you can tweak this method in such a way that it suits your needs (for example if you want to make it more generic, add a duration argument in there).